# How to create a new pandas dataframe with a key from two columns from a previous one?

Tags: python, pandas

Specifically I'm working with the quora csv file which I loaded into a pandas dataframe and the structure goes like this.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
id| qid1| qid2| question1text  |question2text             |is_duplicate
------------------------------------------------------------------------

01|00001|00002|Why do we exist?| Is there life on Mars?   | 0
02|00001|00003|Why do we exist?| What happens after death?| 0
```

So I want to take all the distinct questions with their question id and respective text and pass them in a new dataframe with 2 columns,having only the question id and their respective questiontext like this:

```
---------------------------
qid  |questiontext          |
---------------------------

00001|Why do we exist?
00002|Is there life on Mars?
00003|What happens after death?
```

Comment: Why does the first data frame always have pairs of questions? And which one would you like to retain if there is a duplicate? And how to you define "distinct"?

Comment: it's from quora dataset where it labels if the question pairs are duplicates,but I'm using the dataset for my own thing,I just wanna catalog every question id and text like I mentioned in the example and ditch the rest of the columns. By distinct I meant if there was more than one entry of a question in the original dataframe,it should not be written multiple times in the new one,but only once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `wide_to_long` after adjust your `columns`

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace('text','')
newdf=pd.wide_to_long(df,['qid','question'],i=['id'],j='drop')
newdf
         is_duplicate  qid                    question
id drop                                               
1  1                0    1            Why do we exist?
2  1                0    1            Why do we exist?
1  2                0    2   Is there life on Mars?   
2  2                0    3   What happens after death?
```

---

Then we need `drop_duplicates`

```
newdf=newdf.drop_duplicates(['qid','question'])[['qid','question']]
newdf
         qid                    question
id drop                                 
1  1       1            Why do we exist?
   2       2   Is there life on Mars?   
2  2       3   What happens after death?
```

Comment: How could I delete the columns id and drop if I wanted?

Comment: @thelaw reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: @W-B Thank you friend,this was the anwer I was looking for. Have a nice day